# table append without last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    ​<table id="table">
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>

    <tr id="sum"><td>sum</td><td>sum2</td></tr>
    </table>

    ​<span id="add">add new</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('#add').click(function(){
   $('#table').append('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​
```

How can i make that this add new element with append as penultimate element?
 I would like that #sum still are last element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `insertBefore()`:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>').insertBefore('#sum');
})​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6Zrhs/).

You could also simply use multiple `tbody` elements, one to contain the `#sum` row, and the others for the, in this example, `#content`:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody id="content">
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="sum"><td>sum</td><td>sum2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('#content').append('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6Zrhs/1/).

Or, possibly, using a `tfoot` (though I'm not sure that this a proper use-case for a `tfoot` element:

```
<table id="table">
    <tfoot>
        <tr id="sum"><td>sum</td><td>sum2</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="content">
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6Zrhs/2/).

References:

- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [Tables in HTML documents: Row groups: the `THEAD`, `TFOOT`, and `TBODY` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.before()`

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('#sum').before('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

Really simple :) use `before`

```
$('#add').click(function(){
   $('#sum').before('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
})​;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$('#sum').before('<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>');
```